# ReSharper breaks HTML format

Tags: resharper

Almost every minor edit of .html files immediately breaks the format when ReSharper is enabled.

So I disabled things (e.g. "Auto-format on Enter") in the ReSharper settings under Environment -> Editor -> Behavior:

[image]

And indeed when hitting enter now the format doesn't break immediately when ReSharper is enabled. But when doing other things like deleting empty lines the format still breaks. This doesn't happen when ReSharper is diasbled. Also ReSharper slows down the whole editing experience.

**Main question**: How can I completely disable ReSharper editor / auto formatter support for .html files (and possibly also for .cshtml and .razor)?

Clarification: I'm not talking about the ReSharper "Reformat" or "Code Clean" features that can be run explicitly or automatically on saving (they also break the format but I don't use those features anyway). I'm talking about editing the code via the corresponding Visual Studio editor while ReSharper is enabled. Also I would not like to generally turn off ReSharper auto formatter features because I think they are not that bad for C# for instance.

(Using ReSharper 2022.3.3 and VS 17.5.3).

Answer (score 0):

It's better to file a bug report describing what exactly breaks for you when editing HTML and how to reproduce it. But there's an easy way to disable R# for web-related technologies - just turn off "Web Languages" in "ReSharper | Options | Environment | Products & Features".
[image]

Comment: I assume applying your solution will also disable some nice features like ReSharper underlining the action name argument in @Url.Action() when the name is correct? Or it just disables auto formatting?
I filed two bug report regarding different issues years ago, but they just got shelved, so I'm not doing this anymore.